# phpMailer convert external images to inline images

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using this code in my phpMailer which loops through `<img>` tags using PHPs DomDocument function and generates a CID for each image to add it into PHP mailer as an embedded image instead of using an external URL.

It's working, but there is an issue in GMail where it shows the attachments of the images and they are all called "noname" (they download as .txt files)

It seems to work fine in Outlook.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($body);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
// Loop through each <img> tag and replace the external URL with a CID reference
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $url = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $cid = md5($url); // Generate a unique CID for each image
    $tag->setAttribute('src', 'cid:' . $cid); // Replace the URL with the CID reference
    $image_data = file_get_contents($url); // Get the image data from the URL
    $email->addStringEmbeddedImage($image_data, $cid); // Attach the image to the email using the CID reference
}
$body = $doc->saveHTML();
$body = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $body);
```

Comment: You could try to add the appropriate name and/or mime type to [addStringEmbeddedImage()](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addStringEmbeddedImage).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware "thumbs up" - thank you very much